# Question about estimating number of individuals in a population that belong to 2 sets...

Tags: statistics

Suppose we have a population containing $x$ number of individuals. Out of these individuals we know a number $x_{men}$ are men and $x_{women}$ are women. We also know that there are $x_{veg}$ vegetarians and $x_{non-veg}$. We also assume the following:

$$x_{men} + x_{women} = x$$
$$x_{veg} + x_{non-veg} = x$$

Can we deduce how many vegetarian men there are? If not can we at least make an estimate?

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you saying that some quantities are known (at least as percents)?  Which ones?

Comment: @lulu I literally listed the quantities (and thus percentages) that are known, namely percentage of veg/nonveg and women/men. What isn't clear to you?

Comment: If the numbers are all known, why do you have to "assume" the sum?

Comment: It's just a constraint.... I'm assuming that that you can only belong to either one class or the other for veg/nonveg and men/women.

Comment: Anyway, absent some more information, there's not much to say.  Suppose half are men (and half women) and half are vegetarian (and half not).  Then you could have no vegetarian men at all or all the men could be vegetarian, or anything in between.

Comment: @lulu Ah I see what you mean.  let's also assume there's an equal likelihood for an individual to be a man or woman. Same goes for veg/nonveg.

Comment: @lulu so in your example. Say $x = 10$. Half are men and half are vegetarian. The expected result would be 2.5 vegetarian men, 2.5 vegetarian women, 2.5 non-vegetarian men and 2.5 non-vegetarian women...

Comment: my example meets that condition.  I think you meant to say that the two types were independent, in which case you can certainly get at least a probabilistic estimate.

Comment: Of course, to state the obvious, if you assume the properties are independent you pretty much remove all demographic information from the problem.  Usually, in looking at patterns in a population, people are interested in correlations and such.